# Pdf password protection using Python

Tags: python, pdf, encryption, automation, password-protection

I am trying to password protect a pdf file using python.
I have come across a solution using  PyPDF2 library but the solution does not work on the version of 3.0.0 or above.

Below is the code

```
# import PdfFileWriter and PdfFileReader 
# class from PyPDF2 library
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
  
# create a PdfFileWriter object
out = PdfFileWriter()
  
# Open our PDF file with the PdfFileReader
file = PdfFileReader("myfile.pdf")
  
# Get number of pages in original file
num = file.numPages
  
# Iterate through every page of the original 
# file and add it to our new file.
for idx in range(num):
    
    # Get the page at index idx
    page = file.getPage(idx)
      
    # Add it to the output file
    out.addPage(page)
  
  
# Create a variable password and store 
# our password in it.
password = "pass"
  
# Encrypt the new file with the entered password
out.encrypt(password)
  
# Open a new file "myfile_encrypted.pdf"
with open("myfile_encrypted.pdf", "wb") as f:
    
    # Write our encrypted PDF to this file
    out.Write(f)
```

If anyone can help me with the solution, that will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: You should post the code you have, otherwise its hard to help you

Comment: I suggest using PyMuPDF instead. Save the document like this: `doc.save(filepath, user_pw=userpassword, owner_pw=ownerpassword, encryption=fitz.PDF_ENCRYPT_AES_256)`, where `"fitz"` is the name under which the package must be imported.

Comment: `PyPDF2` is deprecated and has moved to [`pypdf`](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/meta/history.html#pypdf-back-to-the-roots-2023-today) project. It supports also the pypdf2 syntax (essentially from camelcase to underscore)

Answer (score 0):

They have deprecated a number of things. For PyPDF2 version 3 and above, use this:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader
  
output = PdfWriter() # create a PdfWriter object
  
pdf_file = PdfReader("test.pdf") # test.pdf is the pdf you want to protect
  
numPages = len(pdf_file.pages)
  
# grab each page in pdf
for i in range(numPages):
    page = pdf_file.pages[i]
    output.add_page(page) # Add to the output object
  
output.encrypt("pass") # Encrypt output with password "pass"
  
# output actual encrypted binary pdf
with open("encrypted_test.pdf", "wb") as f:
    output.write(f)
```

The new version also allows you to access the page object inside the input pdf file directly. So you can do this too:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader
  
output = PdfWriter() # create a PdfWriter object
  
pdf_file = PdfReader("test.pdf")

# grab each page in pdf
for page in pdf_file.pages:
    output.add_page(page) # add to output object
  
output.encrypt("pass") # encrypt output with password "pass"
  
# output actual encrypted binary pdf
with open("encrypted_test.pdf", "wb") as f:
    output.write(f)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: both methods will not preserve the original PDF **metadata**